# WordPress - Get Current Post Author ID Outside The Loop And Inside A Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to modify a plugin. I need the author id of the current post to accomplish what I am doing. I have tried every other method I have found over internet that claims to get the post author id outside the loop but its not working inside the plugin. I guess its because the plugins might be loaded before the loop variables or something? Please pardon me as I am not a Pro.
Here is what I have tried so far.

1.

```
 $author_id=$post->post_author;
```

2.

```
 global $post;
 $author_id=$post->post_author;
```

3.

```
 $post_tmp = get_post($post_id);
 $author_id = $post_tmp->post_author;
```

4.

```
 $author_id = $posts[0]->post_author;
```

But nothing works in the plugin's directory. Can anyone help?

**Detailed Explanation:**
I am trying to modify [woodiscuz](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woodiscuz-woocommerce-comments/) plugin. The problem with this plugin is that it held comments of even seller for moderation. So if I am the seller and I reply to some buyer in comment, I will have to approve my own comment.
Now to overcome this problem, I am putting a condition that if the author of the post (seller) is commenting, then don't put the comment for moderation.
Here is the function of the plugin that is controlling comments.

```
public function comment_submit_via_ajax() {

    $message_array = array();
    $comment_post_ID = intval(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'comment_post_ID'));
    $comment_parent = intval(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'comment_parent'));
    if (!$this->wpc_options->wpc_options_serialized->wpc_captcha_show_hide) {
        if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
            $sess_captcha = $_SESSION['wpc_captcha'][$comment_post_ID . '-' . $comment_parent];
            $captcha = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'captcha');
            if (md5(strtolower($captcha)) !== $sess_captcha) {
                $message_array['code'] = -1;
                $message_array['message'] = $this->wpc_options->wpc_options_serialized->wpc_phrases['wpc_invalid_captcha'];
                echo json_encode($message_array);
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
    $comment = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'comment');

    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $user = get_userdata($user_id);
        $name = $user->display_name;
        $email = $user->user_email;
        $user_url = $user->user_url;
    } else {
        $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
        $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
        $user_id = 0;
        $user_url = '';
    }

    $comment = wp_kses($comment, array(
        'br' => array(),
        'a' => array('href' => array(), 'title' => array()),
        'i' => array(),
        'b' => array(),
        'u' => array(),
        'strong' => array(),
        'p' => array(),
        'img' => array('src' => array(), 'width' => array(), 'height' => array(), 'alt' => array())
    ));

    $comment = $this->wpc_helper->make_clickable($comment);

    if ($name && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && $comment && filter_var($comment_post_ID)) {

        $held_moderate = 1;
        if ($this->wpc_options->wpc_options_serialized->wpc_held_comment_to_moderate) {
            $held_moderate = 0;
        }
// $held_moderate = 1 -> No moderation          
/*This is the part where I need to put the custom condition*/
    if($post_author_id == get_current_user_id())
    {           
            $held_moderate = 1;             
    }
        $new_commentdata = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'comment_post_ID' => $comment_post_ID,
            'comment_parent' => $comment_parent,
            'comment_author' => $name,
            'comment_author_email' => $email,
            'comment_content' => $comment,
            'comment_author_url' => $user_url,
            'comment_type' => 'woodiscuz',
            'comment_approved' => $held_moderate
        );
        $new_comment_id = wp_insert_comment($new_commentdata);
        $new_comment = new WPC_Comment(get_comment($new_comment_id, OBJECT));

        if (!$held_moderate) {
            $message_array['code'] = -2;
            $message_array['message'] = $this->wpc_options->wpc_options_serialized->wpc_phrases['wpc_held_for_moderate'];
        } else {
            $message_array['code'] = 1;
            $message_array['message'] = $this->comment_tpl_builder->get_comment_template($new_comment);
        }
        $message_array['wpc_new_comment_id'] = $new_comment_id;
    } else {
        $message_array['code'] = -1;
        $message_array['wpc_new_comment_id'] = -1;
        $message_array['message'] = $this->wpc_options->wpc_options_serialized->wpc_phrases['wpc_invalid_field'];
    }
    echo json_encode($message_array);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of `var_dump($post_id)`?

Comment: *When* are you doing this? Are you hooking into anything?